# ffmpeg stuck - invalid dropping st

Tags: ffmpeg

if the input url restart(they add new video in rtmp stream) then in  my ffmpeg i see this

```
PTS 4294794919, next:104020298 invalid dropping st:0
DTS 4294794943, next:104041631 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS 4294794943, next:104041631 invalid dropping st:0
DTS 4294794952, next:109777000 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS 4294795035, next:109777000 invalid dropping st:1
.....
```

ffmpeg command i use is

```
/root/bin/ff1 -i "rtmp://rtmp.example.com/live/video" -i   "/var/www/logo/logo3.png" -filter_complex 'overlay=14:14' -vcodec h264 -crf 25 -preset veryfast -maxrate 600k -bufsize 600k -aspect '640:360' -s '640:360' -acodec aac  -hls_time 10 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 -y "/var/www/html/tv/video2.m3u8"
```

so is there a way to close ffmpeg if this happend or to start working with new input

Answer (score -2):

Try to use -xerror option in ffmpeg command line:

```
-xerror error exit on error
```

Then watch for the process. If it dies, start it again.